# Display collection metafield in product page (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid

there is a way to display a collection metafield in the porduct page?

Each product have a product type that matches the collection, so in the product page of this product I want to display the metafield of that product.

{{ collection.metafields.custom.metafield1 }} doesn't work because of course I'm not in the collection page, so I need to link collection.metafields.custom.metafield1 and product.type, but I don't know how.

Hope I was clear, thank you.

Each product have a product type that matches the collection, so in the product page of this product I want to display the metafield of that product.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with the following code

```
  {% assign collectionHandle = product.type %}      
  {% assign the_collection = collections[collectionHandle] %}
  {% assign my_metafield = the_collection.metafields.custom.categoria_1 %}
  {{ my_metafield.value }}
```

As you suggest it was fun to solve the problem :-D

Comment: And you put this in a custom snippet file that is accessed by the product page? No go for me

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your question, but it would probably go like this. In Liquid, every product has a type. So you would use that on the collections object to get just the collection you want, and from that, the special metafield assigned.

```
{% assign the_collection = collections['{{ product.type }}'] %}
```

That assigns some collection, assuming it exists, based on the current product type, to your variable. Now you would ask for your special metafield that may or may not exist in that collection's metafields.

```
{% assign my_metafield = the_collection.metafields.some_namespace.some_key %}
```

And with that, you could get the value and splash it out there as you please.

```
<h1> {{ my_metafield.value }} </h1>
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work. I try to explain better. I have a metafield in the collection, if I use the variable {{ collection.metafields.custom.metafield1 }} in collection page it woks. But I want to display the metafield of the collection in the product page, where the reference collection is of course the collection of the product. Have I been clearer?

Comment: I mean in the collection "Plates" I have the metafield "cagtegory_1 =  Table". In the product page x, where product type = "Plates", I want to show the value Table. I suppose that with this example is more clear.

Comment: You'll figure it out. I gave you hints, and with enough study of the issue, you'll certainly solve it. That is the fun of work.

Answer (score 0):

yes I understand your point, and I figure out your code and I tried to use it:

```
  {% assign the_collection = collections['{{ product.type }}'] %}
  {% assign my_metafield = the_collection.metafields.custom.categoria_1 %}
  <span>{{ my_metafield.value }}</span>
```

and I don't understand why it does not work.

1. The product type exists and is "Piatti"
2. The collection "Piatti" exists and has the metafield custom categoria_1

I attach a sceenshot of the metafield in order to be more cleare.

[metafield structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiVgg.png)